# Does dateadd() work in temporary view?

Tags: sql, database, databricks

I am trying to use `dateadd()` in temporary view. I am getting an error that says "undefined function". Does this function work in temporary view?

Comment: In a word - yes. If you share some more details perhaps we'll be able to help you.

Comment: What is a temporary view?

Comment: What database is it to have a temporary view? Would you share backend name and view definition.

Comment: Which dbms???  I've never heard of temporary view.

Comment: Also, be aware that multiple database products have functions called `DATEADD`. They can be *completely* different (date/time processing is one area with great variance between products)